# Migrate D6 ImageField Extended captions to D7 File Entity Inline captions

Tags: migrations, tokens, media, files

First of all, I am completely new to the Drupal world and my apologies if I fail at clearly explaining my issue, or if I am missing something that should be obvious.

I "inherited" a D6 website just as D6 reached end of life, and decided to migrate it to D7 (fun little introduction to Drupal, right?).

My main issue after days of tinkering is that I want to use image captions that were originally created thanks to the [ImageField Extended](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_extended) module (v. 6.x-4.2), which was replaced in D7 by the [File Entity Inline](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module (v. 7.x-1.0-beta1).

The original D6 captions were saved into a table called `content_field_figure` along with other information in the form `a:3:{s:5:"title";s:10:"Figure 5.4";s:7:"caption";a:3:{s:4:"body";s:383:"This is the caption text";s:6:"format";s:1:"1";s:5:"style";s:9:"formatted";}s:3:"alt";s:0:"";}`, whereas the new caption field created with File Entity Inline saves the data in a table called `field_data_field_caption`, on its own, under `field_caption_value`.

In my formatters, the original captions were called via the [imagefield-extended-caption] token in D6, whereas the new ones (created with the custom "caption" field created with File Entity Inline) are called with the [file:field_caption] token.

I would love to be able to **merge the existing D6 caption data into where File Entity Inline stores the new caption data, so I can use both the original captions and the newly created ones** with the same [file:field_caption] token, and also edit them in the multi-line text editor that I have set up in my figure field.

How would I go about it?